# Are Extended Attributes Indexed?

Tags: filesystems, search, search-engines, attributes

Are desktop search applications like Beagle or Tracker able to index extended attributes like they do with the other file's attributes? If so, that means that a user can define this extended attributes and search for the files based on them right?

Answer (score 0):

I think GNOME Activity Journal is able to track extended attributes. I couln't find anything about Tracker, so I made a file and added an attribute to test it:

```
$ echo "Lorem ipsum sit amet consectetur" > ./x.txt

$ setfattr -n user.testing -v "this is a test" x.txt
```

Then run `tracker-search "this is a test"` and you get 0 results. If you run `tracker-control -F`, this will show you that all process are done indexing your files. Conclusion: it doesn't work on extended file attributes.